# error while importing HDF5 and h5py module

Tags: python, error-handling, module, bioinformatics, genome

I am trying to use predixcan software. In that one of the script utilise h5py module. When I run the script, and it gives the following error:

```
Could not import HDF5 expression INFO - Could not import h5py module
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Install h5py with `pip install h5py`, if you are using pip, or with `conda install h5py` if you are using Anaconda.

Comment: I did use the command: conda install h5py                                                                                         But its still showing the same error.                                                                                            INFO - Could not import HDF5 expression
INFO - Could not import h5py module