# error in importing the module in anaconda environment

Tags: python, linux, import, module, anaconda

I am trying to run a code but its showing this error:

```
INFO - Loading model
INFO - Preparing genotype dosages
INFO - Setting whitelist from available models
INFO - Processing genotypes
INFO - Preparing prediction
INFO - Could not import HDF5 expression
INFO - Could not import h5py module
```

The conda environment has these package but I don't understand why it is not able to import them.

Comment: Duplicate Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69169499/error-while-importing-hdf5-and-h5py-module

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.